# リスト内包表記内で複数のappend処理をしたい

Tags: python

Pythonで、リスト内包表記を記述する場合、次のような処理ではエラーは出ません。

```
list_a = []
[list_a.append(i * 2) for i in [1, 6, 9]]
print(list_a)
```

しかし、次のように、複数のリストに値をappendする場合などはエラーになります。

```
list_a = []
list_b = []
[list_a.append(i * 2);list_b.append(i * 3) for i in [1, 6, 9]]
print(list_a)
print(list_b)
```

エラー内容は、`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`です。

複数のリストにappendしつつエラーを出さない方法はありますか？

Comment: `()` で囲んで一つのタプルにしてしまう方法が考えられます。`[(list_a.append(i * 2), list_b.append(i * 3)) for i in [1, 6, 9]]`

Comment: ありがとうございます。その方法で出来ました。

Comment: 解決されましたら”解決済”にしましょう。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

()タプルを使用することで出来ました。

```
list_a = []
list_b = []
[(list_a.append(i * 2),list_b.append(i * 3)) for i in [1, 6, 9]]
print(list_a)
print(list_b)
```